# "Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'" при попытке установить связь с графической картой

Tags: docker, cuda, nvidia, runtime

Я пытаюсь запустить чатбота h2o-gpt на моём компьютере, но у меня возникли проблемы с графической картой NVIDIA. Я получаю сообщение об ошибке "Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'", что указывает на то, что среда выполнения контейнера NVIDIA не может взаимодействовать с видеокартой. Я предполагаю, что это, скорее всего, связано с тем, что драйверы NVIDIA установлены или настроены неправильно. Но все же я могу использовать nvidia-smi. Вот сообщение об ошибке:

```
(base) user@user-16GB-computer:~/dev/project/chatbot-rag/v2_h2ogpt/h2ogpt-docker$ sudo docker compose up
[sudo] password for user: 
Attaching to h2ogpt
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Похоже, что я не могу работать со службами nvidia:

```
(base) user@user-16GB-computer:~/dev/project/chatbot-rag/v2_h2ogpt/h2ogpt-docker$ sudo systemctl start nvidia-container-runtime
Failed to start nvidia-container-runtime.service: Unit nvidia-container-runtime.service not found.
```

Но driver, похоже, работает:

```
(base) user@user-16GB-computer:~/dev/project/chatbot-rag/v2_h2ogpt/h2ogpt-docker$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jan 15 18:29:04 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.146.02             Driver Version: 535.146.02   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P0              N/A / 125W |      8MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2440      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Не знаю, связано ли это, но сейчас мой компьютер работает очень медленно. Я читал что-то о том, что GEForce приносит кучу модулей, работающих в фоновом режиме, которые не служат никакой цели и замедляют работу машины.